# SIP connection for iOS in Swift & implement audio & video call with Door Phone

Tags: ios, swift, sip, voip, callkit

I am currently trying to implement audio & video call feature for door phone: https://www.tcsag.de/en/ . I have tried different framework for connection with my IOS App to TCS Door phone. But couldn't finalise the implementation.

Please help me on this so I can complete this feature.

Thanks in advance,
Ratneshwar

Comment: some details? code?

Comment: Hey Anton, thanks for reply. Here is link details for reference:
https://www.linphone.org/docs/liblinphone/
https://www.vocal.com/webrtc/websockets-and-sip-over-websockets/
https://www.tcsag.de/produkte/produktdetail/?tx_products_produktdetail%5Baction%5D=show&tx_products_produktdetail%5Bcontroller%5D=Produkte&tx_products_produktdetail%5Bid%5D=200&tx_products_produktdetail%5Bproduct%5D=172&cHash=23e6b338fe428d6bf93a5806a5142187